# Where Can I found docu for Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore extension?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am searching documentation for the `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore` extension in the viewe V7, but I can't found it .

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/

Just I found in the viewer V2 :  https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/markupscore/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this is not available in V6 and V7 docs, I will notify the team, but you can find it here for now  - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/reference/javascript/markupscore/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a mirror of the v6 and v7 markup tool extension (and measurement), with webpack build script:

> https://github.com/wallabyway/forge-markup-measure-extensions

**Examples:**

For an example of using the markup extension with PDF, see here:

> https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/fast-pdf-viewingmarkup-inside-forge-viewer

For serializing the measurement tool bits to json and back from json:

> https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/area-planning-tool-forge-viewer-and-mysql

Adding an SVG 'stamp' to your 2D sheets:

> https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-svg-your-2d-sheets-forge-viewer

These are examples of why you might want to start customizing the markup/measure tool extension and when you need to read the actual code, override the class built-in methods or 'go-rogue' and change the code completely.

[image: Acme stamp example]

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to use the information from the current version of https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/ and the API information (https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest /docs/index.html)

You can also review this example: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/tree/master/src/Viewing.Extension.Markup2D

Comment: Having a mirror copy on GitHub, means that you are not locked into a viewer version.  You can use GitHub's neat ability to fork a branch, track the differences in future versions, and easily merge those changes with your custom branch.